# Cannot Resolve Symbol 'Rounded Transformation'

Tags: java, android

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

This the dependency of picasso that i downloaded, After downloading it i use it in the project

```
Picasso.with(context)
            .load(R.drawable.user)
            .centerCrop()
            .resize(avatarSize, avatarSize)
            .transform(new RoundedTransformation())
            .into(holder.ivUserAvatar);
```

Though i get a red code on RoundedTransformation showing cannot resolve Symbol 'RoundedTransformation' 
Am not used to using Picasso so i need some help

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you don't have this class .

You can use this class and try again.

```
class RoundedTransformation implements Transformation {
    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

        Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            source.recycle();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
                BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        float r = size / 2f;
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

        squaredBitmap.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "circle";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Transformations are not part the library yet . So you need to add them as per your need .

There are already a bunch of optimized transformations available  which you can use directly. 
1. [wasabeef/picasso-transformations](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations)
2. [TannerPerrien/picasso-transformations](https://github.com/TannerPerrien/picasso-transformations)